# Laravel 5.1, is it possible to send collection to Mail template

Tags: php, email, laravel-5.1

```
Mail::send('emails.mytemplate', $mymodel, function ($message) use ($email) {
      $message->from('info@mail.com', 'Info')
              ->sender('info@mail.com', 'Info')
              ->replyTo(env('MAIL_REPLY_TO', 'info@mail.com'), 'Info')
              ->to($email)
              ->subject('You have new mail');
});
```

gives

`Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Mail\Mailer::send() must be of the type array, object given....`

since the data I want to send is somewhat complex I would really like to send `$myModel` collection to the template and pull the data from the relations of `MyModel` in there instead of parsing all the data to new multilevel array and passing that to the `Mail::send(...)`;

Is that the right way to go or should I just parse the model and all of its relations to a new array and go with that?

Comment: Why not do `$mymodel->toArray();`

Comment: OMG i just tried this and it seems all of the data is sent when I use the `toArray()` method. I'll examine it further but I can't believe how or why did I assume that with toArray will I lose related data. Thank you @Digitlimit ..... EDIT:

Ok, the problem was that I already wrote the template with collection in mind so now I need to rearrange the template or find another way to use model methods to display data the way I want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to send an actual object to the mail template. Simply change your logic to:

```
Mail::send('emails.mytemplate', ["mymodel" => $mymodel], function ($message) use ($email) {
      $message->from('info@mail.com', 'Info')
              ->sender('info@mail.com', 'Info')
              ->replyTo(env('MAIL_REPLY_TO', 'info@mail.com'), 'Info')
              ->to($email)
              ->subject('You have new mail');
});
```

That way, in your `emails.mytemplate.blade.php` you can still access data off of that object by using:

```
<p>My Model's name is {{ $mymodel->name }}</p>
```

Comment: This is the most simple way, and I get to keep my prewritten template.  However I would replace ` ["mymodel" => $mymodel]` with `compact(order)` to keep it even simpler. Thank you Tim.

Comment: No problem. I was actually working on a `Mail::send()` function myself when I saw this question; didn't want you to have to switch to array notation. Glad I could help!

Comment: Thanks, this saved me so much time and it cleared some things in my head too. I just hope everything will be working when I move to queues.